# Redirect to new url ends session even if end response is false

Tags: asp.net, session, response.redirect

On our asp.net site we use **Response.Redirect(url, false)** to redirect user to **payment provider**. Before redirect, we store some data in session, because we need it for postback. Immediately when we make our redirect, the **session is ended** and on postback new **session with the same id** is created. Our stored data is of course - gone.

Does anyone know why redirect ends session even if parameter **endResponse** is set to **false**? When I'm using different payment provider (redirect to different url), the session is not terminated and I don't lose data that was stored in session.

Comment: What code is written after the `Response.Redirect(url, false)` line. Can you share this function?

Comment: by the way, `endResponse` has nothing to do with session. `endResponse` specified whether after redirection the current code will continue executing or this thread shall be killed (as the new url is executed on a new thread)

Comment: Response.Redirect is the last line in function. Payment provider then returns us back to our application (we set values in configuration).

Comment: And thank you for clearing endResponse for me:)